# Не появляется меню, после нажатия на "гамбургер"

Tags: html, bootstrap

Почему-то при клике на 'гамбургер' не появляется меню, использую **bootstrap 3.3.6**, **bootstrap.min.js* подключен. Подскажите, будьте добры.

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fuide">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"  aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/About/logo_w.png" alt="Brand"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">text1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">text6</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За открытие отвечают два скрипта. Проверьте ещё раз подключение jquery и bootstrap.min.js

Например, откройте просмотр кода страницы и попробуйте перейти по ссылкам, которые заданы в <script src="..."></script>. Должно открыться содержимое скриптов.

Comment: Да, верно. Спасибо.
*Причина была в опечатке подключения скрипта.